# Is this a bug in MERGE, failing to implement FOREIGN KEY properly?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using the following tables to implement subtypes, which is a very common approach:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Vehicles(
    ID INT NOT NULL, 
    [Type] VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Vehicles_PK PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    CONSTRAINT Vehicles_UNQ_ID_Type UNIQUE(ID, [Type]),
    CONSTRAINT Vehicles_CHK_ValidTypes CHECK([Type] IN ('Car', 'Truck'))
);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Cars(ID INT NOT NULL,
    [Type] AS CAST('Car' AS VARCHAR(5)) PERSISTED,
    OtherData VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Cars_PK PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    CONSTRAINT Cars_FK_Vehicles FOREIGN KEY(ID, [Type])
        REFERENCES dbo.Vehicles(ID, [Type])
);
GO
-- adding parent rows
INSERT INTO dbo.Vehicles(ID, [Type]) 
VALUES(1, 'Car'),
(2, 'Truck');
```

I have no problem adding a child row via INSERT, as follows:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Cars(ID, OtherData)
VALUES(1, 'Some Data');

DELETE FROM dbo.Cars;
```

Surprisingly, MERGE fails to add one child row:

```
MERGE dbo.Cars AS TargetTable
    USING 
        ( SELECT    1 AS ID ,
                    'Some Data' AS OtherData
        ) AS SourceData
    ON  SourceData.ID = TargetTable.ID
    WHEN NOT MATCHED 
        THEN INSERT (ID, OtherData)
        VALUES(SourceData.ID, SourceData.OtherData);

Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "Cars_FK_Vehicles". The conflict occurred in database "Test", table "dbo.Vehicles".
The statement has been terminated.
```

Is this a bug in MERGE or am I missing something?

Comment: It seems to be passing an empty string as `type`. If I remove the check constraint and add a row `INSERT INTO dbo.Vehicles(ID, [Type]) VALUES (3, '');` Then the `Merge` works for `VALUES(3, 'Some Data');
`

Comment: @MartinSmith - it's a persisted constant though...

Comment: @JNK - Yes I didn't say it was correct behaviour (it seems decidedly incorrect), I just said that's what appears to be happening.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I agree with your conclusion, good catch!

Comment: A workaround if you really want you use merge would be to have regular column type in cars with not null and a default constraint like this `[Type] varchar(5) not null default 'Car'` and also add a check constraint `CONSTRAINT Cars_CHK_ValidType CHECK([Type] = 'Car')`. I think that would add up to the same behavior as the persisted column and the merge works just fine.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: this is exactly what are using. What I really want is to have rock solid data integrity. I can and maybe should get rid of MERGE, as it seems to be not fully robust yet. I waited until R2 and thought that would be enough to have it reliable. Probably I was wrong.

Comment: Open a connect item. While I'm not sure that 'persisted constant' should behave like a default constraint, I'm convinced the behavior of INSERT and MERGE should be consistent to each other (either both fail the insert or both succeed).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like a definite bug in `MERGE` to me.

The execution plan has the `Clustered Index Merge` operator and is supposed to output `[Cars].ID,[Cars].Type` for validation against the `Vehicles` table.

Experimentation shows that instead of passing the value `"Car"` as the `Type` value it is passing an empty string. This can be seen by removing the check constraint on Vehicles then inserting

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Vehicles(ID, [Type]) VALUES (3, '');
```

The following statement now works

```
MERGE dbo.Cars AS TargetTable
    USING 
        ( SELECT    3 AS ID ,
                    'Some Data' AS OtherData
        ) AS SourceData
    ON  SourceData.ID = TargetTable.ID
    WHEN NOT MATCHED 
        THEN INSERT (ID, OtherData)
        VALUES(SourceData.ID, SourceData.OtherData);
```

But the end result is that it inserts a row violating the FK constraint.

### Cars

```
ID          Type  OtherData
----------- ----- ----------
3           Car   Some Data
```

### Vehicles

```
ID          Type
----------- -----
1           Car
2           Truck
3
```

Checking the constraints immediately afterwards

```
DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS  ('dbo.Cars')
```

Shows the offending row

```
Table         Constraint          Where
------------- ------------------- ------------------------------
[dbo].[Cars]  [Cars_FK_Vehicles]  [ID] = '3' AND [Type] = 'Car'
```