# Postgres SQL Exclusive OR (XOR) CHECK CONSTRAINT, is it possible?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, xor

Is it possible to make a XOR CHECK CONSTRAINT?

I'm doing it on a test table I just made that is called **test** and has 3 columns:

- id, bigint
- a, bigint
- b, bigint

I made a check constraint for this:

```
(a IS NOT NULL AND b = NULL) OR (b IS NOT NULL AND a = NULL)
```

[Which apparently would work in MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127356/add-a-sql-xor-constraint-between-two-nullable-fks)

I tested it by doing this:

```
INSERT INTO public.test(
    id, a, b)
    VALUES (1, 1, 1);
```

Which should fail, seeing as it doesn't evaluate to TRUE on either side of the OR.
However, it's inserting just fine.

When I look at what postgres actually stored as constraint I get this:

```
(a IS NOT NULL AND b = NULL::bigint OR b IS NOT NULL AND a = NULL::bigint)
```

I heard AND takes precedent over OR so even this should still work.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Preferably one that is also possible with three or more columns? I understand that those might be more complicated though.

EDIT: Changing

```
= NULL
```

to

```
IS NULL
```

give me:

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type boolean to bigint
```

Comment: It's `IS NULL`.

Comment: @jarlh "ERROR:  cannot cast type boolean to bigint" if I do that.

Comment: Seems like you're (trying) to use some Postgresql specific SQL here (that I don't know.)

Comment: @Blanen: You are saying `a IS NOT NULL` is allowed and `a IS NULL` throws an error? That is not likely. Please show your complete check constraint

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, you are right. Just pgAdmin4 was being weird I guess.

Comment: This wouldn't work in SQL Server either if you have the default setting of `ANSI_NULLS = on`. But `ANSI_NULLS = off` is deprecated in SQL Server and won't be available in future versions.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't compare NULL values with `=`, you need `IS NULL`

```
(a IS NOT NULL AND b is NULL) OR (b IS NOT NULL AND a is NULL)
```

For a check constraint you need to enclose the whole expression in parentheses:

```
create table xor_test 
(
  id integer primary key, 
  a integer, 
  b integer, 
  check ((a IS NOT NULL AND b is NULL) OR (b IS NOT NULL AND a is NULL))
);

-- works
INSERT INTO xor_test(id, a, b) VALUES (1, null, 1);

-- works
INSERT INTO xor_test(id, a, b) VALUES (2, 1, null);

-- fails
INSERT INTO xor_test(id, a, b) VALUES (3, 1, 1);
```

Alternatively the check constraint can be simplified to

```
check ( num_nonnulls(a,b) = 1 )
```

That's also easier to adjust to more columns

Comment: `num_nonnulls` is a great find, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 65):

Right, the `a = NULL` and `b = NULL` bit was the issue as @a_horse_with_no_name indicated. You might also consider this derivative, which doesn't require the `OR` operator:

```
create table test 
(
  id integer primary key, 
  a integer, 
  b integer, 
  check ((a IS NULL) != (b IS NULL))
);
```

Of course that works exclusively with only two column `XOR` comparison. With three or more column `XOR` comparison in a similar test table you could resort to a similar approach more like this:

```
create table test 
(
  id integer primary key, 
  a integer, 
  b integer, 
  c integer, 
  check ((a IS NOT NULL)::INTEGER + 
         (b IS NOT NULL)::INTEGER + 
         (c IS NOT NULL)::INTEGER = 1)
);
```

Comment: Shouldn't your multi-column example use `IS NOT NULL` instead of `IS NULL`? If A `IS NULL` (1) and B `IS NULL` (1), but C `IS NOT NULL` (a valid XOR condition), then the resultant sum would be 2 instead of 1 and fail the check.

Comment: Well, that depends on how the constraint is defined. XOR isn't well defined for more than 2 inputs, but "exactly 1 is true" is a common literal translation. As defined here, the check expects exactly one and only one NULL. A variant check for exactly one and only one is NOT NULL is left to the reader as an exercise, as are all of the "no more/less than" variants.

Comment: As written, this example checks "exactly 1 is NULL", whereas the more likely desired check is "exactly 1 is NOT NULL" - as is the case for a 3-or-more-way XOR operation.

Comment: Read comments above yours. Editing an answer to add your opinion is generally poor form.

Comment: Note: `!=` is the alias of `<>` which is the SQL standard notation.

Answer (score 7):

This is clear Exclusive-OR. Why not define it as a boolean operator first? It might be useful for other cases too.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.xor (a boolean, b boolean) returns boolean immutable language sql AS
$$
SELECT (a and not b) or (b and not a);
$$;

CREATE OPERATOR # 
(
    PROCEDURE = public.xor, 
    LEFTARG = boolean, 
    RIGHTARG = boolean
);
```

Then CHECK `((a IS NULL) # (b IS NULL))`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Vic. I've a similar test in a vue. A least 2 or more columns must be not null, in a left join.

```
SELECT
    (tbl1.col1 IS NOT NULL)::INTEGER +
    (tbl2.col1 IS NOT NULL)::INTEGER +
    (tbl3.col1 IS NOT NULL)::INTEGER +
    (tbl4.col1 IS NOT NULL)::INTEGER +
    (tbl5.col1 IS NOT NULL)::INTEGER +
    (tbl6.col1 IS NOT NULL)::INTEGER > 1 AS
    b_mult_cols
FROM tlb1
    LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tlb1.col1 = tlb2.col1
    LEFT JOIN tbl3 ON tlb1.col1 = tlb3.col1
    LEFT JOIN tbl4 ON tlb1.col1 = tlb4.col1
    LEFT JOIN tbl5 ON tlb1.col1 = tlb5.col1
    LEFT JOIN tbl6 ON tlb1.col1 = tlb6.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to using `num_nonnulls(a, b, c, ...) = 1` as indicated by a_horse_with_no_name before, you can also use arrays to this end with an arbitrary number of columns.

Example:

```
CONSTRAINT chk_whatever CHECK (cardinality(
    array_remove(
        array[a, b, c, d, e, f, g], NULL
    )
) = 1)
```

The logic:

1. Put all the column values in an array
2. Remove all NULLs from that array
3. Check that only one value is left.

Tested on Postgres 11.