# SQL Server - Create FK Using a literal as one of the keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a code list table with a group name and key id. Instead of using discreet tables for every look-up (key/description pair), they are all in a single code_list table. I would like to generate a FK using a literal and column name as the relational key.

Example:

```
Order table -> "State" & order.state_id -> code_list.group_name & code_list.key_id.
```

The statement below, obviously does not work, but is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order] WITH CHECK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_State_Code_List] 
  FOREIGN KEY('State', [State_Id]) 
  REFERENCES [dbo].[Code_List] ([Group_Name], [Key_Id])
```

I am using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a literal value.

You could add a persisted computed column with the desired value and reference that in the FK definition, used in some super type / sub type models [as this questioner demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7771869/73226).

But you appear to be implementing the "[one true lookup table](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/look-up-tables-in-sql-/)" anti pattern here.

You should just have a separate table for State and a regular foreign key.